How to fetch uncommon data from two different tables in Oracle SQL (query A - query B)
I have two select queries, where query A has all the data and I have another query with some data. We need to fetch the uncommon data from both query records. Let's say (query A - query B).
Please find below example with existing data and expected output.
Query A:
SELECT meaning 
FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values 
WHERE lookup_type = 'XXLSC_SCHEDULE_PRO_LKP';

Output of Query A:



Meaning




Autoinvoice Import Program


Purge Concurrent Request and/or Manager Data


Create Intercompany AP Invoices


Rollup Cumulative Lead Times


Record Order Management Transactions



Query B:
SELECT DISTINCT fcs.program
FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr,
     apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcp,
     apps.fnd_responsibility_tl frl,
     apps.fnd_user fu,
     apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v fcs
WHERE fcr.phase_code = 'P'
  AND fcr.request_id = fcs.request_id
  AND frl.language = 'US'
  AND fcr.requested_by = fu.user_id
  AND fcr.responsibility_id = frl.responsibility_id
  AND fcr.status_code IN ('P','Q')
  AND fcp.language = 'US'
  AND fcp.source_lang = 'US'
  AND fcr.concurrent_program_id = fcp.concurrent_program_id
  AND fcr.requested_start_date >= SYSDATE
  AND fcs.program IN (SELECT meaning FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values 
                      WHERE lookup_type = 'XXLSC_SCHEDULE_PRO_LKP');

Output of query B:



Program




Autoinvoice Import Program


Create Intercompany AP Invoices


Record Order Management Transactions



Below is the final expected output (fetch the uncommon data from both queries - query A which will have all the data will be minus from query B records):



Meaning




Purge Concurrent Request and/or Manager Data


Rollup Cumulative Lead Times



Can it be achieved from INNER JOIN/OUTER JOIN/EXPECT/UNION or anything else?

Look into either the MINUS set operator or an outer join with a IS NULL predicate to test for the lack of a matching row.

As Paul said, MINUS. As an aside, don't write joins like that. Use explicit join syntax ex FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b ON a.key = b.key . Implicit join syntax ex. FROM tableA a, tableB b WHERE a.key = b.key has been considered "old" for 20 years. Once queries get more complicated the old syntax becomes very difficult to read. SQL Server originally deprecated it in 2005.

On a side note: You are using an outdated join syntax that we used in the 1980s and early 1990s. You should re-write the joins and use up-to-date syntax ([INNER] JOIN in your case).

Another side note: DISTINCT is very, very often an indicator for an inappropriately written query. Why are there duplicate syou must remove? Often this is because you join when you should use EXISTSorIN` instead (or when you have involuntarily written a cartesian join because of the old syntax).

"query A - query B" is actually a great way of describing it, as Oracle has a minus set operator:
SELECT meaning -- This is query A
FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values 
WHERE lookup_type = 'XXLSC_SCHEDULE_PRO_LKP';
MINUS -- Set operator here
SELECT fcs.program -- This is query B, with the DISTINCT modifier removed
FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr,
     apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcp,
     apps.fnd_responsibility_tl frl,
     apps.fnd_user fu,
     apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v fcs
WHERE fcr.phase_code = 'P'
  AND fcr.request_id = fcs.request_id
  AND frl.language = 'US'
  AND fcr.requested_by = fu.user_id
  AND fcr.responsibility_id = frl.responsibility_id
  AND fcr.status_code IN ('P','Q')
  AND fcp.language = 'US'
  AND fcp.source_lang = 'US'
  AND fcr.concurrent_program_id = fcp.concurrent_program_id
  AND fcr.requested_start_date >= SYSDATE
  AND fcs.program IN (SELECT meaning FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values 
                      WHERE lookup_type = 'XXLSC_SCHEDULE_PRO_LKP');


Thanks alot!
minus operator worked for me.
